# Not Able to Run PowerShell Script from CMD

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, powershell-2.0

I want to execute a PowerShell script from Command Prompt. I have verified script from PowerShell, it worked fine. I went to script location and executed it as

```bsh
./hyperv_disk_ops.ps1 -op 'getDiskAttachmentInfo' -vmid '{6612D0CB-BCC3-44D4-988B-526500578D54}' -disk_ids ("Microsoft:7B036CE0-5D67-46BA-AF7B-B2AFD8DD7946\83F8638B-8DCA-4152-9EDA-2CA8B33039B4\0\0\D")
```

But when I tried running it from command prompt as

```bsh
powershell.exe C:\hyperv_disk_ops.ps1 -op 'getDiskAttachmentInfo' -vmid '{6612D0CB-BCC3-44D4-988B-526500578D54}' -disk_ids ("Microsoft:7B036CE0-5D67-46BA-AF7B-B2AFD8DD7946\83F8638B-8DCA-4152-9EDA-2CA8B33039B4\0\0\D")
```

it gave me an error

> ERROR: Failed to find object of [Microsoft:7B036CE0-5D67-46BA-AF7BB2AFD8DD794683F8638B-8DCA-4152-9EDA-2CA8B33039B400D] disk which is associated with [{6612D0CB-BCC3-44D4-988B-526500578D54}] VM.

Both are exact same but why it is not running from Command Prompt?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell - escaping string passed to child process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276662/powershell-escaping-string-passed-to-child-process)

Comment: As your error message is _not_ emanating from the command-line parsing but comes from code within your script, it would be helpful to see your script.

Answer (score 0):

Try running from the command prompt with double backslashes, like so:

`powershell.exe C:\hyperv_disk_ops.ps1 -op 'getDiskAttachmentInfo' -vmid '{6612D0CB-BCC3-44D4-988B-526500578D54}' -disk_ids ("Microsoft:7B036CE0-5D67-46BA-AF7B-B2AFD8DD7946\\83F8638B-8DCA-4152-9EDA-2CA8B33039B4\\0\\0\\D")`

It looks like, in the error you provided, all of the slashes are being omitted in the disk path.