# PowerShell -command from batch Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I've tried every combination I can think of, but the best I can come up with is an encoding issue.  I know how to work around this by using -EncodedCommand or creating a small .ps1 script, but that's not what am looking for a couple of reasons.

So I hope, someone here knows what's going on here.

This works at PowerShell command prompt:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://127.0.0.1:8989/api/series" -Method Get -Header @{"X-Api-Key" = "1234"}
```

But when I try to pass it from command prompt or batch it fails!

```
powershell.exe -command "& {Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://127.0.0.1:8989/api/series" -Method Get -Header @{ "X-Api-Key" = "1234" } }"

powershell.exe -command "& Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://127.0.0.1:8989/api/series" -Method Get -Header @{ "X-Api-Key" = "1234" }"

powershell.exe -command Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://127.0.0.1:8989/api/series -Method Get -Header @{ "X-Api-Key" = 1234 }

powershell.exe -command @{Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://127.0.0.1:8989/api/series -Method Get -Header "X-Api-Key" = 1234 }
```

and many, many, many more combinations ;(

**update 160614**
removed all the error examples, not needed anymore.

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34282945).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the entire thing and escape the quotes:

```
# If running within cmd
powershell.exe -command "& Invoke-RestMethod -Uri \"http://127.0.0.1:8989/api/series\" -Method Get -Header @{ \"X-Api-Key\" = \"1234\" }"

# If running within powershell
powershell.exe -command "& Invoke-RestMethod -Uri \`"http://127.0.0.1:8989/api/series\`" -Method Get -Header @{ \`"X-Api-Key\`" = \`"1234\`" }"
```

Comment: `PowerShell.exe` command line parser actually use backslash for escaping not backtick.

Comment: @PetSerAl: Actually your shell escapes the quotes. Need to update. If you run within cmd.exe you need to use \

Comment: To run from PowerShell it need to be ``\`"``. `PowerShell.exe` command line parser need to see ``\`` in the command line.

Comment: @PetSerAl: powershell.exe somehow transforms `powershell -command "& echo ``"Hello world``""` to `hello\nworld` being outputted (hello world over two lines). Updated the post as you described.

Comment: Thank you so much! as soon as I say the "\" I remember I use that for findstr to search on multiply lines.

Answer (score 0):

For me I would do

```
powershell -Command "Invoke-Webrequest https://file.com -Outfile file.file" & cls
pause >nul
```